# Is it true that user activities decline on Stack Exchange during holidays or weekends?

Tags: discussion, statistics, traffic

Do you know any empirical studies, evidence, or proofs to show that user activities on Stack Exchange (or Stack Overflow) decline during holidays or weekends?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Traffic on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (25k+ only) follows a pattern. I bet you can guess which two days of the week correspond to the dips:

[image]

That spike is the beginning of Winter Bash 2020. Traffic on other sites (at least the ones mostly used in the workplace, such as Stack Overflow) exhibits the same type of behaviour. On sites focused on hobbies, e.g. Chess, there is no such pattern:

[image]

but I bet you can guess when the Netflix series The Queen's Gambit started...

Comment: [Agadmator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIMaTKOZG-8) [covered it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaMv4cQtEnw).